# Set CMTrace Font

Tags: windows, logging, powershell, log-files, sccm

Might be a bit of a long shot but I was wondering if anyone knew of, or could speculate on, a way to change the default font of [CMTrace](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36213). It seems to use some Sans-Serif font. I'd like to change it to any mono-spaced font so output from PowerShell (or the console) stays lined up.